# using PropertyInfo to assign a value to a wrapper class with a custom indexer

Tags: c#, reflection, indexer, propertyinfo, setvalue

I need to assign a value via **PropertyInfo**.

I'm having some problems when the type of the property is my custom class (a wrapper around a dictionary, designed to contain multiple language versions of the same text).

It looks like that:

```
    public class MultilingualString
    {               
        Dictionary<string, string> Versions;
        public string this[string languageCode]
        {
            get
            {
                if (Versions.Keys.Contains(languageCode))
                {
                    return Versions[languageCode];
                }
                return null;
            }
            set
            {
                if (Versions.Keys.Contains(languageCode))
                {
                    Versions[languageCode] = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Versions.Add(languageCode, value);
                }
            }
            // [blah blah other stuff...]    
        }
```

So; now I have this **PropertyInfo** object - and a string value I would like to assign with a default language code.

```
certainPropertyInfo.SetValue(
   instance, // an instance of some class exposing a MultilingualString type property 
   someString,
   new[] { "eng" }); // some default language code
```

This throws an exception.

I guess the last argument of **SetValue** is meant to be a collection index and it doesn't work with a custom indexer.

Effectively what I'm trying to do is, obviously:

```
   instance.msProperty["eng"] = someString;
```

But I am only given the name of msProperty, that's why I'm using reflection.

So far I have thought about implementing an implicit operator (within the MultilingualString class), allowing to convert string values to MultilingualString... but I can see some problems with that approach eg. this static operator would hardly have a way of "knowing" what the default language code is.

Can I achieve my goal via reflection?

Comment: do you have the propertyinfo object? And if you do, how did you get the object? Are you sure you have the right one?

Comment: Also, why do you need to use reflection?

Comment: I know the type of the object and I am dynamically invoking it (using Activator) and populating it with data from DataTable. Users of the application I am developing are supposed to map DataTable columns to different properties of my business classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indexer is a property of its own. You need to get the indexer property of the instance in that certain property of yours:

```
var multilingualString = certainPropertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
multilingualString.GetType().GetProperty("Item").SetValue(multilingualString,
                                                          someString,
                                                          new object[]{ "eng" });
```

`Item` is the default name for the indexer property.

If you are using .NET 4.0, you can use the new `dynamic` type:

```
dynamic multilingualString = certainPropertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
multilingualString["eng"] = someString;
```

Comment: like your .NET 4.0 solution... Never thought about it before.

Comment: But do you really need to use the `GetValue` first? Can't you just run `dynamic multiStr = instance; multiStr["eng"] = someString;`

Comment: GetValue takes at least two arguments, the second one being "optional index values", and it returns null in any case. I'm on .NET 3.5, so I can't use dynamic.

Comment: @Tomas: No, you can't do this, because instance is NOT of type `MultilingualString` but of a type containing a property of type `MultilingualString`. What you could do, if you would know the name of that property would be the following: `dynamic multiStr = instance.TheKnownPropertyName; multiStr["eng"] = someString;`

Comment: that might be so, but why do he need to do a `GetValue` at all when using `dynamic`. If he has the instance variable he should be able to set it right away, right?

Comment: ah... i see... missed that part.

Comment: OK I realized know why GetValue was returning null nevertheless. I forgot the property wasn't automatically initialized (not in the constructor), and I forgot to take care of that; silly me. After fixing that, your solution works perfectly - thanks!